# How can I make one scrollbox smaller than the other?

Tags: html, css

I'm coding with CSS. Below is my current code for the scrollbox, but I'm curious if there is a way to make an additional scrollbox smaller than this one.

```
.scrollbox {
  height: 370px;
  width: 415px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: medium;
  color: #fff;
  background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: sure - just add a new class that has the properties you want!

Comment: use `width` and `height` less than this one.

Comment: If your goal isn't to make a copy of this code with a smaller `height` and call it `.scrollbox2` for example, then you will need to provide more code and context to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your text, Please check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kbjn8vLu/20/) hope it helps

```css
.scrollbox {
  width: 210px;
    height: 210px;
    overflow: auto;
    color:red;
    text-align:left;
    margin:0 auto;
  
}
```

```html
    <div class="scrollbox">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nmmy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat voluonutpat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nmmy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat voluonutpat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nmmy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat voluonutpat.
    </div>
```